# Cannot deploy Tomcat6 webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, tomcat6

I am trying to deploy a new web app on an external server. This server is running Tomcat6 and it already has a web app running under its hood without problem. (I go to the URL and it works.) I deployed my webapp.war file to the apache*/webapps directory, and when I type "ant list" to query the manager, I get:

```
[list] OK - Listed applications for virtual host localhost
[list] /:running:0:ROOT
[list] /manager:running:0:manager
[list] /webapp-x:running:1:webapp-x
[list] /mywebapp:running:0:mywebapp            <------ my web app
[list] /docs:running:0:docs
[list] /sample:running:0:sample
[list] /examples:running:0:examples
[list] /host-manager:running:0:host-manager
```

You can see that it shows my web application as running, but when I go to my.url.com/mywebapp in a browser, I get a 404 Not Found Error. **However, when I go to my.url.com/webapp-x in a browser, the web application runs and displays itself without any problem. Why is this? What could be different about webapp-x?

Comment: I got this error when I ran `ant deploy` on my project: "Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored (please use webxml attribute to war task)" Could it be relevant?

Comment: "my.url.com/webapp-x i " is this a valid URL ??? Shouldn't u run the page at ur localhost server?

Comment: That's just a placeholder... I am not giving the real URL out on this site. It's in the form https:// x.y.z/webapp-x

Comment: do you have access to manager? perhaps you can check the status using the provided manager webapp.

Comment: I don't even know if I have access to manager. I'm working through SSH with a remote server. I can't just open up a web browser and type localhost. When I visit https://my.url.com/manager, I get a Forbidden access error. I don't know how to override this...

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs to make sure the webapp didn't throw any exceptions on startup, which prevents the context from coming up.

Comment: I don't see any exceptions. Besides, I put a dummy application in webapps that doesn't have any .class or .java files. All it has is an index.html file and a WEB-INF/web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

try stopping it and delete the warfile and the mywebapp directory then restart the server and redeploy it usually fixes the problem for me